Highlight row while clicking button in ajax table
I want to add highlight class on selected row in ajax table while clicking edit button. I don't know why my code is not working. Could you help me? Thanks in advance.
function getData(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>copycontrol/getData",
                method:"post",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    var html='';
                    var i;
                    var count= 1;
                    html+='<table id="copyTable" class="table table-bordered"><tr><th class="border_none"style="width:2%"></th><th  class="border_none" style="width:86%">Procedure Description</th><th class="text-center" style="width:12%">Operations</th></tr>';
                    for(i in data){
                        html+='<tr><td>'+count+'</td><td onclick="copy(this)">'+data[i].name+'</td><td><button type="button" class="delete" id='+data[i].id+'><i class="fa fa-trash" title="Delete" style="font-size:20px;"></i></button><button type="button" class="edit" title="Edit" id='+data[i].id+'><i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:20px;"></i></button></td></tr>';
                        count++;
                    }
                    html+='</table>';
                    $('#showData').html(html);
                }
            });
        }

$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
            var eID = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#copy_info').text("Edit row.");
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>copycontrol/fetchSingleData",
                method:"post",
                data:{eID: eID},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data){
                    
                    var i;
                    for(i in data){
                        $('#name').val(data[i].name);
                    }
                    $('#single').val(eID);
                    $('#submit').text("Edit");
                    $('#submit').val("update");
                    $('#name').focus();

                    var selectedRow = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(0)").text();
                    $("tr:nth-child(" + selectedRow + ") ").addClass('highlight');

                    if($('#submit').val() == "submit")
                    {
                        $('#success').text("Row data was successfuly edited.");
                        $('#success').fadeOut(3000);
                        
                    }
                }
            });
        });

This code produces error: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child()..."
var selectedRow = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(0)").text();
$("tr:nth-child(" + selectedRow + ") ").addClass('highlight');


What does console.log(selectedRow) yield?

What does console.log($(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(0)").length)  and going back... what is this at the time you use it?

console.log(selectedRow) prints empty line

Ok, I found solution. Thank you for your attention. I added thead and tbody in function getData then I moved selectedRow and addClass before ajax. Now it is working.

Instead of fetching the row number and then finding the row by that number, you can directly add a class to the closest row from the clicked button since the button clicked triggers an AJAX call this reference inside the AJAX success callback does not refer to the edit button but to the success function itself you need to preserve the reference to the button outside the AJAX call.
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    var eID = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#copy_info').text("Edit row.");

    // Preserve 'this' context to use inside AJAX success callback
    var button = $(this); // 'this' refers to the clicked '.edit' button

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>copycontrol/fetchSingleData",
        method: "post",
        data: {eID: eID},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i in data) {
                $('#name').val(data[i].name);
            }
            $('#single').val(eID);
            $('#submit').text("Edit");
            $('#submit').val("update");
            $('#name').focus();

            // Add 'highlight' class to the closest 'tr' from the button
            button.closest('tr').addClass('highlight');

            if ($('#submit').val() == "submit") {
                $('#success').text("Row data was successfully edited.");
                $('#success').fadeOut(3000);
            }
        }
    });
});

